# Python/Selenium Identifying an element issue

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

im trying to log in with python into webpage, but for some reason i cant get correct login element no matter what i try, because im noob and this is my first attempt.

This is supposed to be the element from webpage:

```
<label class="">Username</label>
<input type="text" formcontrolname="username" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched xh-highlight">
```

I have tried search by label without success:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Username')]")
```

I have tried search by class:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched"]')
```

I have tried search with CssSelector:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[formcontrolname='Username']")
```

I have even tried full road:

```
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app/div[@class='app-container']/ng-component/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col']/div[@class='card']/ng-component/div[@class='card-body']/form[@class='ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']/div[@class='form-group'][1]/input[@class='form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched']")
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, please help

Comment: [Link to image of the source code.](https://imgur.com/E9zJSQK)

Comment: There are several possible issues. Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epOU1.png)

Comment: This link is not enough. 1) There are maybe iframes there 2) maybe you are missing waits etc...

Answer (score 1):

To locate the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  username = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[formcontrolname='username']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  username = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@formcontrolname='username']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues:

1. You may be missing a wait / delay to let the page loaded before you try accessing the elements.
2. The element may be located inside an iframe, so you will have to switch to that iframe in order to access the elements inside it.
3. The locator may be not unique.
   To give more clear answer we need to see the we page you are working with and all your relevant code